# Twitter's Streaming API (statuses/filter) & Erroneous Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

**Background**

I'm using Twitter's `statuses/filter` [Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) and filtering with a geo-bounding box.

**Problem**

Of the tweets that I can "sanity check" (e.g. tweets that have a Point-type coordinate which, thus, allows me to check if it falls within the bounding box), **greater than 80%** do **NOT** fall within the bounding box.

In short, there are a ton of false positives coming across the wire.

**Good news**

The good news that it seems the API *does not* **miss** any Tweets (i.e. so far, every tweet I've published within the box **is** caught by the API).

The bad news is ... the 80% of false positives.

**Ask**

I'm curious if anyone has noticed the same phenomenon (and/or knows how to get better results).

Not that it likely matters, but I'm using the `TwitterAPI` Python library.

**Sample code if you want to try**

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI("your", "codes", "go", "here")

swLon = -74
swLat = 40
neLon = -73
neLat = 41
stream = api.request('statuses/filter', {'locations': str(swLon) +','+ str(swLat) +','+ str(neLon) +','+ str(neLat) })

for tweet in stream:

# verify the tweet has geo information (and a usable point-type coordinate pair)
if 'geo' in tweet:
    if tweet['geo'] is not None:
        if tweet['geo']['type'] == 'Point':               
            # get the tweet's coordinates
            tweetLat = tweet['geo']['coordinates'][0]
            tweetLon = tweet['geo']['coordinates'][1]

            # sanity check to ensure the tweet is actually within our market bounding box
            if tweetLat < neLat and tweetLat > swLat and tweetLon < neLon and tweetLon > swLon:
                print "good"
            else:
                print "false +"
```